# jemandem nachrennen

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have just found this text:

> Aber als das Kaninchen seine Uhr aus der Westentasche zog, nach der Zeit sah und eilig fortlief, sprang Alice auf; denn es war ihr doch noch nie vorgekommen, ein Kaninchen mit einer Westentasche und einer Uhr darin zu sehen. Vor Neugierde brennend, **rannte sie ihm nach** über den Grasplatz, und kam noch zur rechten Zeit, um es in ein großes Loch unter der Hecke schlüpfen zu sehen.

Does it mean, that it is possible to say "jemandem nachrennen" with the meaning "to chase somebody" ?

Comment: Yes: http://www.dict.cc/?s=nachrennen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *nach-* prefix [conveys the imitating part.](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=nach-) And *rennen* the action of running. Together it means, indeed, what you supposed. Other examples are

1. **nachahmen**, repeat somebody's words, imitating
2. **nachmachen**, repeat someboby's action (also positively)
3. **nachsingen**, sing after somebody's example

Comment: It’s not necessarily imitating; you can _nachrennen_ someone who is not running, just had a head start (e.g. they forget something when they leave, and you only notice two minutes later). So I’d interpret it as spatial in this case.

Answer (score 1):

### YES

»Jemandem nachrennen« means to follow somebody by running.